# Position absolute, make right column height same as left column

Tags: html, css, css-position

I struggle with following problem: we have absolutely positioned two divisions, one is for content, one for navbar. Left one contains huge amount of text, so it's usually stretched far over page height. I want the right one (navbar) to stretch as well. Sadly, I can't obtain it with known methods.

```css
.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
}

.left .leftc {
  background: red;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="leftc">
    ABC <!-- large amount of text -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">

</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ch3shireDev/1kvh8sjw/4/)

*Note:* I know how to make right bar with fixed position but I want navbar to be scrolled with whole page as well as rest of content. No fixed positions please.

Comment: My workaround for now is to set color of the navbar as the body color.

Comment: There have been a number of ways to achieve this effect, documented in many how-to's around the web, which I'm sure you could find with a search; but now you can use _[flex layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)_ (as people have answered) or _[grid layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using `display: flex` on the `body`. (I erased all the position settings)

```js
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  $(".leftc").append("<p>xxx</p>");
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
.left {
  width: 70%;
}
.leftc {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.right {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <div class="leftc">
    ABC
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tknna6ww/1/

Comment: You don't need `leftc`. Also using relative units for width in the basic layout is most always a bad idea (unless you **really** know what you are doing)

Comment: I just used the original HTML code from the question, that's the reason for leaving `leftc` in there. And why should percentage width be a bad idea? (I think I *do* know what I am doing...)

Comment: I know, I just meant that @Ch3shire doesn't need it for the effect. Because you never want it to change its width when you resize the browser? I mean that just creates tons of layouting issues and bugs, is really confusing for the user and gives a false impression of reponsiveness

Comment: I love it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The left `div` is stretched by its content, not by a defined height. You can set the height of the right `div` to the same height of the left one using JavaScript:

```
$(".right").css("height", $(".leftc").css("height"));
```

Note that you have to put this line after the page is rendered to make sure that the browser has already calculated the correct height. Here is a demo:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  $(".leftc").append("<p>xxx</p>");

$(".right").css("height", $(".leftc").css("height"));
```

```css
.left,
.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
}

.left .leftc {
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <div class="leftc">
    ABC
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">

</div>
```

Comment: I guess I need to use jQuery after all :) I wanted to know if there is some pure-CSS method. Probably not.

Comment: You can do it in CSS, but you'll have to change your design a bit. I don't know if you can do that in your project. My answer will work with your current design (and almost any design, really).

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather simple if you can put them in the same container.

That container then only needs to have `display: flex;` (and `flex-direction: row;` since you want it horizontally)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The newer way to do this, that is [widely but not fully](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) supported is [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

```css
.wrapper-of-your-whole-site-potentially {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "left right";
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-of-your-whole-site-potentially">
  <div class="left">
  
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-direction: row;` is the default - you don't need to define it. And 50px isn't 30% in most cases...

Comment: yeah I know, but it works with `70%` and `30%` just as well, but using percentages for layouts like this is rather strange and usually a bad idea. But if she has a really good reason for it she could use that too.

Comment: using percentages is definitely not strange at all, and also not a bad idea

Comment: For layouts it is. Like I have explained in the comments of your answer

Comment: @SourceOverflow - you haven't explained _why_ you claim it is "strange". Reasons? Source citations?

Comment: I wrote: _Because you never want it to change its width when you resize the browser? I mean that just creates tons of layouting issues and bugs, is really confusing for the user and gives a false impression of reponsiveness_ That it is strange was referring to the confusing behavior. Percentages are usually only used on absolutely sized parents or when doing some effects, but never for layouts (at least not since 2010). Why do I need to cite sources? I gave you the arguments themselves, as much as a comments can hold at least.

Comment: I mean think about it: When resizing the browser window, would you expect the text to start wrapping differently unless the edge touches the text? And when you anchor the window to one half of the screen, would you expect the sidebar to halve in size? No, most people don't and in fact I don't know any side that would do that. What happens is that the layout changes to the mobile (or tablet) version before wrapping is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

make red side `height: 100%;`

```css
.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
}

.left .leftc {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="leftc">
    ABC <!-- large amount of text -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">

</div>
```